# Help! Issue with Automatic Weight Paint

Tags: rigging, bones

in blender
i just rigged all my bones
and i am trying to do the automatic weight paint feature
problem is when i do that the whole mesh alligns to the bones and it rotates the mesh and it goes all crap ill show you in a screenshot:
[image: Before Weight Painting]
Before applying weight paint
[image: After Applying Weight Paint]
After applying Weight Paint

Ill put the .blend file here and when i move the arm ik it also moves the head for some reason, if you guys could maybe fix my bones or just redo the bones for me that would be great :)
P.S im doing this for a project and i really need the bones finished to get onto animating :D

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TRY6WbiTL-Wm5IRWpDd3NSOXM is the blend file

Comment: The goal of this site is not to fix problems for you, but maybe help you understand what is going wrong so that you can fix them yourself...

Comment: remember i said "if" :D

Answer (score 1):

To have your weighting work, just select the armature, go to pose mode and search for the function "apply pose as rest pose". Then do the weighting.

Anyway there are some good practices not to have problems with armatures:
- Apply (CTRL A) location, rotation and scale to both your character and your armature.

- See your character in center page from the front view (Numpad 1): yours is rotated 90 degrees
- In edit mode set all the bones roll to 0, unless differently necessaire.
- uncheck the deforming control from ALL non deforming bones
- Have at least 3 edges loop in every bone joint that must bend: search the internet for good deformation topology, there are a lot of examples.

Have fun.

Comment: How do i search for a function?

Comment: press spacebar and type it (you must be in the right window, i.e. pose mode). Anyway it's in the lower header: pose - apply pose as rest pose.